# Python CV2 Color Space Conversion Fidelity Loss

Tags: python, image, colors, opencv

Observe the following image:

[image]

Observe the following Python code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("rainbow.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) # convert it to hsv
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR) # convert back to BGR
cv2.imwrite("out.png", img)
```

Here's the output image:

[image]

If you can't see it, there's a clear loss of visual fidelity in the image here.  For comparison's sake, here's the original next to the output image zoomed in around the yellows:

[image]

What's going on here?  Is there any way to prevent these blocky artifacts from appearing?  I need to convert to the HSL color space to rotate the hue, but I can't do that if I'm going to get these kinds of artifacts.

As a note, the output image does not have the artifacts when I don't do the two conversions; the conversions themselves are indeed the cause.

Comment: Maybe it's an 8-bit image? The Hue is mapped from 360 degrees to 180 degrees to stay under 255 - the limit of an unsigned 8-bit number. So there's a 2 degree hue granularity.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, you are correct, it is an 8-bit image.  So what can I do to avoid this?

Comment: I'm not at a computer to test, but I would try going to `float` rather than 8-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back at a computer now - try like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("rainbow.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = img.astype(np.float32)/255           # go to 32-bit float on 0..1

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) # convert it to hsv
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR) # convert back to BGR
cv2.imwrite("output.png", (img*255).astype(np.uint8))
```

I think the problem is that when you use unsigned 8-bit representation, the Hue gets *"squished"* from a range of 0..360 into a range of 0..180, in 2 degree increments in order to stay within 8-bit unsigned range of 0..255 causing steps between nearby values. A solution is to move to 32-bit floats and scale to the range 0..1.